# Doctrine: IN-Operator in entity-repository's findBy?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, findby

I want to make a `findBy` in doctrine with the `IN`-Operator, like in SQL:

```
...WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Is it possible to do this in the criteria array of the entity-repository's `findBy`?

```
this->entityRepository->findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);
```

Or must I do this with DQL?

Comment: No to findBy.  Yes to DQL.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can!

`$repository->findBy(['column_name' => ['value1', 'value2', '...']]);`

Comment: Came across this and it works fine. In case someone is wondering this performs an IN () query and not an OR query.